# Angular approach to reuse a dropdown list component in a large Enterprise app

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm new to Angular and I'm starting to build an enterprise grade large app with Angular 5.

I've choosen the Reactive Forms approach to build the app forms because there will be large forms in this app.

For what I learned so far, I understand that if I want to reuse a section of a form I can build a component from it, and this component could be reused in the same module.

But, what about if I want to reuse a smaller part? I'm thinking in building smaller components like dropdown lists that will be present in many forms, in different modules of the app. Dropdown list components that receive an injected service and auto-fill.

I've followed this approach in other large enterprise apps but with other technologies and frameworks.

Is this advisable in Angular?
How would I proceed if I'm creating my forms with a FormBuilder?

I appreciate any advise or guideline.

Comment: You may want to check out this video as you try to nest pieces of forms: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8

Comment: Thanks Deborah! That video helped me very much. It seems that custom forms controls are the way to go.